# Comparing two tables of different size, with multiple columns in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, list-comparison

Looking to use VBA to compare two tables, with three columns each against each other. Beginner here and very lost.

They may have a different amount of entries each, and there may be some in table A that aren't in table B, and vice versa

Some of the individual Columns may match but trying to work out how to make sure all three columns are compared as one against all three columns in the other table

For example

xyz123 55.50 12/07/21 if compared with XYZ123 54.55 12/07/21 will show up as not a match, because the middle column is a different number.

Have attached a picture below. For the most part, and unlike the photo, each table will be in a completely random order, and its unlikely that there will be the same entry in table 1, row 1, as table 2 row 1

[image: For example]

Ideally, I'm trying to create two new table to the right of the original tables, the first one being the entries table 1 has, that table 2 does not have. The second one being the entries table 2 has, that table 1 does not have.

Have attached an example below of the end result I'm looking for out of this. The four rows on the left are entries that the first table has but the second table doesn't, and the rows to the right are all entries that the second table has, but the first table does not.

[image: Desired Output]

I've tried to search on this but haven't found something that matches what I've got, and I'm struggling to adapt someone else's code to my specific problem

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a direct answer to your problem but is this data also in a database somewhere or are you familiar with Ms Access? As you could open the tables in Access, and it is pretty easy to do this kind of thing with data bases.
If not, then yes, it is do able with VBA. Numerous ways of doing it.
The simplest is to scroll through one table a line at a time and compare it with every row in the other table and match or not. This will work with small tables and be easy and quick but for large data tables it would be wasteful and may take a long time to complete.

Comment: Hi Perfo, thank you for the response

No, not in a database, this information is emailed to us, usually in all sorts of formats. The idea was we would manually copy and past it into the table like the above questions, and then automate the matching process. The tables are rarely more than 70 entries long so not too concerned about the efficiency of this. Someone is currently doing this by hand so anything would be better.

Comment: OK, so a simple go through one line at a time would probably be achievable and the easiest way for you to get started. What bits do you need help with ? I don't mean to offend your coding skills but can you open up the VBA editor and code for next loops and the like ?